# how to change the picture in custom listview in Android?

Tags: android, image, listview, android-custom-view

In this program, I have a custom listView including a text & a picture. The pictures are in drawable folder. I want any of the pictures to be shown on each line of my list along with the related text, but I don’t know how??? I’ve uploaded a sample of my program and its link below. 
As shown in picture!

I’d be really thankful if u could help me with some instructions!

[Picture server 1](http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-01/28535302012085182071.jpg)

[Download Android Project-server 1](http://www.upiha.com/uploads/e92536_SmsBox.rar)

Comment: Include relevant code in the question, not behind a link to some unknown site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of mistakes in your code...... Try to do something like this in your getView method of your adapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
if (convertView == null) {
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listbox_item, parent, false);
holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_THE_IMAGE);
holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_THE_TEXTVIEW);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
holder.img.setImageResource(SET_THE_IMAGE);
holder.tv.setText(SET_THE_TEXT);

holder.tv.setTypeface(mTypeface);

return convertView;
}
```

Also create a private class ViweHolder which improves the performances of the listView by 15%, and should look like something this in your case....

```
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView img;
    TextView tv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<Drawable> imgs;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

public AListAdapter(Context context, List<Drawable> drawables) {
    this.context = context;
    this.imgs = drawables;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imgs.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return imgs.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return imgs.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row;
    if (arg1 == null) {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowLayout, null);
    } else {
        row = arg1;
    }
    ImageView img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowImg);
    img.setBackground(imgs.get(arg0));
    TextView txt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
    txt.setText("TEST1");
    return row;
}

}
```

As you can see, StackOverflow lets you post code :P
BTW, did you search for this before asking? I didn't even try but I'm quite sure this same question has been asked before.